# Move file from networked computer to server

Tags: shell

Is it possible for a script to run on the server like so:

```
mv /path/to/source /path/to/destination
```

Where the source is a networked computer, and the destination is the server itself? If so, what would the path to source look like?

Answer (score 8):

If you've mounted the filesystem from the server via a networked filesystem such as NFS, CIFS, sshfs, etc. then just perform a local operation within the mount point.

If the server filesystem is not mounted locally then you'll need to use a tool such as scp or rsync to transfer the file over the network; see the documentation for the tool for the specific syntax required.

Answer (score 0):

In the question title you talk about `moving` a file and then you said you need to `run` it on the server. If I understand your question correctly you want to run a local script on a remote server? You could use `ansible` for that from your local caomputer:

```
ansible ${SERVER} -m script -a "script.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have ssh access to the remove machine this can be accomplished with `scp`:

```
scp user@RemoteHost:/path/to/source /path/to/destination
```